# Can't retrieve managed package's apex classes for reference in SFDX project?

Tags: salesforcedx

I feel like I'm missing something basic here..

My scenario:

- Using SFDX project, NOT using scratch orgs (for reasons), retrieving and deploying to a dev sandbox.
- Currently have a managed package installed on the sandbox (a Docusign package from the appExchange)
- Said managed package metadata is *not* part of my local SFDX project (this is the problem I'm trying to solve)
- Have written an apex class in my local SFDX project that references a class+method that is part of this Docusign package.
- This is giving me a reference error in VS Code, as the project does not see the Docusign apex class

I tried `SFDX force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass`, but that didn't pull the classes in the package

Specifying the class name didn't help, as it wasn't found.

I also tried: `SFDX force:source:retrieve -n "DocuSignPkgName"`... which retrieves the pkg successfully, sure, but puts it in its own directory structure rather than integrating it into the project folder. This doesn't help me address the reference error I'm getting.

Am I not supposed to be able to include managed package components in my SFDX project? If not, how are we supposed to effectively develop against package components?

**Edit to respond to SFDCFox**

To give your solution a try, here's how I updated my `sfdx-project.json` file:

From

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0"
}
```

To

```
{
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0",

  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "package": "unlockedPackageTest",
      "versionNumber": "0.1",
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "dependencies": [{
          "package": "Docusign Apps Launcher@2.3.1"
        }]
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "Docusign Apps Launcher@2.3.1": "04t3u000003X3cuAAC"
  }
}
```

Now I'm not clear, but it seems like with this change I've just 
A) declared that my sfdx project is now an unlocked package with a name and version number, and 
B) claimed that my package has a dependency on the installed Docusign package

However, I'm not sure what to do with this change to my json file. I tried another `SFDX force:source:retrieve` on the project to see if it would now pull in the depended-upon package metadata, but it did not. Plus, the dependency error is still showing up in the Problems tab of my homemade class in VS Code, and in the deployment errors if I try to push to my sandbox.

I have confirmed that the apex class and its method that I am referencing in my own code is `Global`, and that if I were to recreate my class directly in sandbox via dev console, the reference error wouldn't appear.

The problem I'm trying to solve seems to be purely getting VSCode + SFDX to retrieve and acknowledge this dependency.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but adding the dependency to my sfdx-project.json file doesn't resolve the issue. Are there any example projects that illustrate this scenario (trying to reference Apex classes in a managed package) that I can use as a template to figure out what I'm obviously not understanding?

Comment: @jerhewet I had assumed the managed package's apex wasn't being pulled into my SFDX project, but it turns out I was incorrect, and the reason I was getting the error wasn't because my project couldn't find the Apex class + method I was calling, but rather because I was passing the wrong var type to it. You might want to double check that.

Comment: As far as I can tell I'm doing everything correctly (virtually the same scenario you had), but the dependency that's available from the SF Developers Console (NS.TheApexClassname) in my sandbox is missing from my VSCode-SFDX project. There are so many possible/potential configuration settings I have the sinking feeling I'm missing something -- especially if it's working for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve the contents of managed package classes via the API, but presumably, if you're trying to make an Unlocked Package, you simply forgot to specify the dependency:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "package": "myPackageName",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "definitionFile": "config/features.json",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": true,
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "docusign@X.Y.Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "47.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "docusign@X.Y.Z": "04t..............."
  }
}
```

To get the 04t value, use:

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list
```

In the above JSON, replace X.Y.Z with the version number provided from the output of this install list.

Comment: Thanks... I'm not creating an unlocked package, rather I've got a standalone homemade class+trigger that references both an object and a class that is part of this managed Docusign Package. I've created these in my local VS Code sfdx project, but because the managed package's metadata isn't pulled into my SFDX project, the references aren't recognized and causing deployments to fail.

Comment: `sfdx force:package:installed:list` does show the  desired managed package in the list, so I will try modifying my `sfdx-project.json` file... however, I was under the impression that file is only used when working with scratch orgs? I'll give it a shot but I'm deploying/retrieving from a dev sandbox

Comment: @smohyee If the packages are presently installed, it shouldn't fail. The Scratch Org Definition File is used both for creating Scratch Orgs and creating Unlocked Packages. Are you sure you're deploying to the correct org? Are the classes and methods global? Anything that you can save in the Developer Console should also work in VS Code.

Comment: I updated my post to share the changes I made to my `sfdx-project.json`, if you could please take a look and let me know if I understood it right. Also, am I correct that you are saying that I NEED to make my project an unlocked package to involve a dependency like this? What if I just wanted to write a standalone class that references a class sitting in an installed package? I wouldn't need to mess with packaging if I was doing this in dev console, I'm pretty sure

Comment: One thing to note: I installed this package in my sandbox AFTER I created my sfdx project and tied it to that sandbox org. I figured that shouldn't matter - after all, I can create metadata in my sandbox and retrieve it to my sfdx project using a `force:retrieve` command, why not packages as well?

Comment: Honestly your offhand reference has me learning about an entire new paradigm with internal org development based around unlocked packages..

Comment: @smohyee You might try using the "refresh definitions" option found in the Command Palette. Maybe that's what's wrong? It still shouldn't prevent deployments from happening. Regardless, Unlocked Packages are pretty cool and you can do a lot of interesting things with them, you might want to try the trailhead on them.

Comment: I only see "SFDX: Refresh SObject definitions" in the command pallete, which doesn't seem to do anything... but I'm following the trailhead and it appears I need to use an SFDX command to actually define and create my unlocked package. Prior to all this, I had tried adding the `dependencies` param under the `packageDirectories` in my default `sfdx-project.json` file, but got an error message saying a name and version number needed to be specified... so it seems like an unlocked package is absolutely required to involve any dependency on a managed package

Comment: ok, update: I was chasing down the wrong rabbit hole. My dependency error wasn't because my sfdx didn't see the managed packages in the dev org, or any need to set up unlocked packages... I just passed the wrong var type to the method!

Comment: @smohyee Oh, lol, sometimes it's the easy things that trip us up.